# Ionic2 background-image don't appear on device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've set a custom class .categories e in my Ionic2 app in order to style it with a custom background. The CSS for the background is:

```
.categories {
  background: url('../../assets/img/dark.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Everything works just fine in Chrome (using ionic serve), but when I build and run on device, all I see is a plain white background.
I've tried adjusting the path for the background image to assets/img/dark.jpg but no luck. If anyone could possibly help me I'll appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please try below my code

Comment: thank you but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright i think all what you have to do is to change the URL to

```
background-image: url('../assets/img/dark.jpg');
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you so much Mohamed, you just saved my day. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

**Background information on the background-image problem**

Ionic seems to take all your scss-files, transpile and merge them into one giant css-file 
(main.css) which is stored in the `{project}/www/build/` directory.

If your background images originally reside in the `{project}/src/assets/img/` directory, they are copied to `{project}/www/assets/img/`.

So regardless of where, or how deep, in the **src** directory tree your source scss-files are (commonly `{project}/src/pages/{pagename}/{pagename}.scss`) you need to consider that the paths of referenced images need to be relative to the **build** directory, not the directory of your scss-file.

When testing the app on a desktop browser using `>ionic lab`, absolute paths will also work, for example:

```
background-image: url('/assets/img/dark.jpg');
```

But in my experience this will not work on actual devices nor in emulators. So don't use it.

As Bouzafour Mohamed mentioned, you need to use the following format to reference your background image.

```
background-image: url('../assets/img/dark.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Link will be not like you used
it has to be like relative path to your file

such as your file is on

```
src > pages > example >example.scss
```

then you must use image path as

```
.categories {
background: url('../../assets/img/dark.jpg');
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that's what I did actually. it's working on browser (ionic serve) but on my android device, the background is not showing.. I appreciate your help

Comment: How can it be possible. It works in all my project.. Please send the path details of your image and your ionic page to correct.

Comment: My image "dark.jpg" is in www/assets/img folder. and the style is in app.scss file